# How can I create a "Create Triggers" add-on menu option UNLESS the installed triggers already exist?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

From Google:

> If an add-on is either installed for the current user or enabled in the current document, the add-on is loaded in the document, which causes it to appear in the Add-ons menu and start listening for the simple triggers onInstall(e), onOpen(e), and onEdit(e)

When running the onOpen simple trigger, the the auth mode is at best **LIMITED**, meaning you get the following error when trying to check on the user installed triggers:

> You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.getUserTriggers. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp

So, we can create a menu item which says "Create Triggers" where the user can click on, and we'll be in **FULL** auth mode then.  Only problem with this is, it would be ideal if the "Create Triggers" menu option did **NOT** appear IF the triggers already exist.

One possible solution, which Google seems to hint at in their documentation, is to set a property whenever the installed triggers are created.  Then, the simple onOpen trigger can just create the "Create Triggers" menu option only if the property has been set.  However, a user could accidentally delete the installed triggers manually without clearing the property, which would prevent the user from ever seeing the "Create Triggers" menu option again - a severely broken state.

Another possible solution is to create an additional **installed** onOpen trigger to help set the menu items. However, this creates a race condition between the **simple** onOpen trigger, and the **installed** onOpen trigger - both accessing the same add-on menu. Making things much worse, there doesn't seem to be a way to "read" the add-on menu - making no reliable way to communicate whether installed triggers exist to the simple onOpen trigger.

I am currently trying to resolve the race condition using both the LockService and PropertiesService.

There must be an easier solution - I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: `However, a user could accidentally delete the installed triggers manually without clearing the property, which would prevent the user from ever seeing the "Create Triggers" menu option again - a severely broken state.` Provide a option in the Menu to "Reset"

Comment: That is a solution - it's not ideal, because the user has an extra menu option to get distracted by, but at least it's reliable.

Comment: If the trigger runs, the function run by the trigger can access the trigger uid e.triggerUid .. You can check the last run time or save time run/uid in propertiesService. Check to see if  trigger is probably disabled  according to your script logic?